# How to remove the name of the firebase app from appearing while logging in?

Tags: css, firebase

[image]

As you can see that the name of the firebase app appears in the 'Choose an account' page. Is there any way with which I can remove that or rename it?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.